# Suppose 55% of a group a students can pass an exam...

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose 55% of a grouo of students can pass an exam, if 100 students are randomly selected, what is the probability that at least 50 but less than 60 students pass the exam? Use histogram correction.

This question was given to me as a review for an upcoming exam.

My math:

$\overline{x} = 100*0.55 = 55$

$\sigma = \sqrt{np(1-p)}= \sqrt{100*0.55(0.45)} = 4.97493$

What we need to calculate: $P( 50 \leq x \lt 60)$

$=P(X < 60) - P(X < 50)$

$=P(Z< \frac{\overline{x}-correction-X}{\sigma})-P(Z< \frac{\overline{x}-correction-X}{\sigma})$

$=P(Z< \frac{60-0.5-55}{4.97493})-P(Z< \frac{50-0.5-55}{4.97493})$

$=P(Z < 0.9045) - P(Z < -1.1055)$

$=0.81713-0.13447$

=**0.6826 or 68.26%**

Is there anything glaringly wrong with my calculations and did I use the histogram correction correct?

Comment: I am just starting statistics and I am wondering why you subtracted the $\text {correction}$. It would be helpful if anyone could explain it as my brain was already seeing it as $P(X \lt 60)=P(Z \lt \frac {60- \mu}{\sigma})$.

Comment: We us the histogram correction (AKA continuity correction factor) when we are using normal distribution as an approximation for the binomial distribution.

Comment: Interesting. Is there any specific reason for $0.5?$

Comment: I believe we use 0.5 because it does not change the bounds of what we are calculating. Since # of students is always going to be an integer, the range of 49.5 to 59.5 is still the domain of what we were originally trying to find with respect to the # of people [50,60)

Comment: Your title need not be the opening sentence of your question; better to state the gist of the actual question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your math seems to be correct. However, I would have written $60 - \mbox{correction}$ as 
 $59 + \mbox{correction}$ to demonstrate that you saw that the upper limit is $59$ and the right-side histogram correction *adds* half a bin.